# Instances and class in Haskell

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I have the following code in Haskell:

```
module Shape where
type Height = Float
type Width  = Float
type Radius = Float
data Rectangle  = Rectangle Height Width 
data Circle = Circle Radius

class (Eq a, Show a) => Shape a where
   area :: a -> Float
   perimeter :: a -> Float

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle h w) = h * w
    perimeter (Rectangle h w) = h*2 + w*2
    show (Rectangle h w) = "rectangle "  ++ (show h) ++ " " ++ (show w)
    (==) (Rectangle h w) (Rectangle c d) = (h == c) && (w == d)


instance Shape Circle where
   area (Circle r) = pi * r**2
   perimeter (Circle r) = 2 * pi * r
   show (Circle r) = "circle " ++ (show r)
   (==) (Circle r) (Circle x) = r == x
```

and I want to add the instances of Show and Eq in order to define the new cases (e.g Rectangle * * == Rectangle * *) but I get the following problem:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Shape           ( Shape.hs, interpreted )
Shape.hs:24:17: `show' is not a (visible) method of class `Shape'
Shape.hs:25:17: `==' is not a (visible) method of class `Shape'
Shape.hs:31:12: `show' is not a (visible) method of class `Shape'
Shape.hs:32:12: `==' is not a (visible) method of class `Shape'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What that it means? And how can I make it work?

---

EDIT: 
The code now:
(line 13 to 31)

```
instance Eq Rectangle where
    (Rectangle h w) == (Rectangle c d) = (h == c) && (w == d)

instance Show Rectangle where
    show (Rectangle h w) = "rectangle "  ++ (show h) ++ " " ++ (show w)

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle h w) = h * w
    perimeter (Rectangle h w) = h*2 + w*2

instance Eq Circle where
    (Circle r) == (Circle x) = r == x

instance Show Circle where
    show (Circle r) = "circle " ++ (show r)

instance Shape Circle where
   area (Circle r) = pi * r**2
   perimeter (Circle r) = 2 * pi * r
```

The error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Shape           ( Shape.hs, interpreted )
Shape.hs:19:5: parse error on input `instance'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: `Float` isn't really a *legitimate* instance of `Eq`. This doesn't relate to your present problem, but it's likely to cause you trouble down the road. If you switch to a better-behaved type like `Rational` (from `Data.Ratio`), you'll run into fewer gotchas in general (but won't be able to take square roots and such).

Comment: If you want to define "standard" instances, don't forget to try `deriving (Show, Eq)`. For custom ones, you do have to write your own code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split out the instances for each type and each typeclass it's an instance of.

```
instance Eq Rectangle where
    (==) (Rectangle h w) (Rectangle c d) = (h == c) && (w == d)
instance Show Rectangle where
    show (Rectangle h w) = "rectangle "  ++ (show h) ++ " " ++ (show w)
instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle h w) = h * w
    perimeter (Rectangle h w) = h*2 + w*2
```

It's just that the `show` and `==` definitions for each type aren't part of the `Shape` instance, they're part of typeclass instances for `Show` and `Eq` that happen to be dependencies of `Shape`.

Comment: I changed it exactly like you say and I get this error:       ' [1 of 1] Compiling Shape          ( Shape.hs, interpreted )

Shape.hs:19:5: parse error on input `instance'
Failed, modules loaded: none.'

Comment: Which line is line 19? What comes before it?  That suggests a missing parenthesis or other syntax error.

Comment: @xBlackout I don't have any problems with that code, I'm not sure what's happening for you? https://ideone.com/Ydq6Oc

Comment: The problem was related with tabulation, not code errors. Thank you!